# how to test a function call with dynamic calldata array?

Tags: unit-testing, ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts, remix

I have a contract function like the following

```
function updateDeps(uint16 parent, uint16[] calldata deps) public
```

And I am trying to create unit tests in remix with the following

```
contract TestContract is MyContract {
    uint16[] deps;
    function testUpdateDeps() {
        deps.push(uint16(2));
        deps.push(uint16(3));
        deps.push(uint16(4));

        (bool success, bytes memory result) = address(this).delegatecall(abi.encodeWithSignature("updateDeps(uint16, uint16[])", 1, deps));
        Assert.ok(success, "should succeed");
    }
}
```

I wrote the test like this because of the [difference between fixed size array and dynamic array](https://github.com/willitscale/learning-solidity/blob/master/support/INVALID_IMPLICIT_CONVERSION_OF_ARRAYS.MD) and that `calldata` cannot be a contract variable and can only be created in function call, thus the `delegatecall`. However, the transaction failed.

How should I test function that takes a `calldata` dynamic array as param?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is with the abi encoding string, there cannot be space between the params in the string, i.e. `updateDeps(uint16,uint16[])` works but not `updateDeps(uint16, uint16[])`

P.S. an additional fyi, if you are using `uint` in your code, which is alias for `uint256`, in the abi signature string you have to specify `uint256` but not `uint`.